# php on submit redirect to another page

Tags: php, redirect

I have a form in my html document and when press submit button, the form calls the file form.php. Now in the form.php, i want to redirect it back to my home page and reset the previous filled form. I have tried the code below but I got a blank page. The Google url is just default.

```html
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
  // To redirect to home page
  header("Location:http://www.google.com");
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: please check server logs and post here if possible

Comment: tip : write `exit()` after `header`

Comment: How do I get that? i'm using Filezilla as ftp client

Comment: @NawshadGhannoo there should be file named `error_log.txt` where the form.php is located .

Comment: Oh yeah thanks. 
Here is the message: 
[09-Oct-2014 06:06:07 UTC] PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/webpro/public_html/dev/form.php:12) in /home/webpro/public_html/dev/form.php on line 16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the javascript way of redirecting the page:

Example :

```
    $url='http://www.google.com';

    echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>';
    die;
```

It may help ...!!

Comment: This works perfectly. Thanks mate. I think this topic is solved. Thanks so much everybody, you guys are awesome.

Comment: Thanks , Happy to help , Stack Overflow Rockzz...!!@@!!

Answer (score 1):

Probably you wrote some echo or print before this header(...). Try `ob_start();`.

For more info follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see your HTML, but have you named your submit button with the attribute `name="submit"` ?

Other case `$_POST['submit']` will be empty and your script do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have used the code which you have. I can able to redirect to google.Please check the below code..In my view I think the problem may be the mail function.check if the mail is coming or not..If mail comes then it would definetly redirects to the google page..

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) 
 {
    $to="test@gmail.com";
    $subject="googletest";
    $body="test";
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body)) 
    { 
        // To redirect to home page
        header("Location:http://www.google.com");
    } else { 
        echo '<p>An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
<form name="form" id="form" action="form.php" method="post">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Yeap thats my html too. I got the email when submit. It just won't redirect. But I've used echo '<script>window.location = "'.$url.'";</script>'; instead of header and it's fine now. Btw do you know how to make this topic solved?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
   $to="abc@gmail.com";
   $subject="Mail";
   $body="redirect";
   $from="xyz@gmail.com";
    if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
        // To redirect to home page
        header("Location:http://www.google.com");
        exit();
    } else { 
        echo '<p>Oops! An error occurred. Try sending your message again.</p>'; 
    }
}
?>
```

Its working on my local server.

Comment: I don't know whats wrong. I have used javascript instead as suggested by Sharaz Nabi and it worked.